# replace with the id if it match with id of other using node js / javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, nodes

```js
const data = [
  {
    system: {
      id: "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "Author" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      shortSlugOption: { "en-us": "some value", "za-op": "random value" },
      mediaFileAssetLink: { "en-us": "some file", "za-op": "file Linl" },
      mediaFileAssetGalary: { hi: "file link 2" },
      singleMediaImage: { hi: "file link single", "en-us": "english link" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "1aBOO8tu3lUsjtICuIbUM5",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "Author" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      short: { "en-us": ["shorts", "values"], "za-op": "short details" },
      shortSlugOption: { "hi-In": "options" },
      booleanField: { "hi-In": "true" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "2pOUGnI1oRD7nsrYs600HA",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "testing" } },
    },
    DataDetails: { testingNewValue: { "en-us": "details value" } },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "new" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      oneReference: { hi: "values 1" },
      multiReference: { "hi-In": "values 2" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "cIb5mqEBRWDD6hrNmFmFE",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "new" } },
    },
    DataDetails: { testingNewValue: { "hi-IN": "jksdsdo" } },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "7kRzyt4PFrX13gHcw3Z1Ko",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "testing" } },
    },
    DataDetails: { testingNewValue: { "en-us": "kknksdo" } },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "2OspeCtNK0sh2cPiuU9jIz",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "dummy" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      short: { "za-op": "dfvndkssa" },
      shortSlugOption: { hi: "sdocjosmdc" },
      mediaFileAssetLink: { "en-us": "jdsojocis" },
      booleanField: { "hi-In": "true" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "2eAmIIuG4xkLvatkU3RUSy",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "dummy" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      dummy: { "en-us": "dshcifdvk" },
      india: { "za-op": "sdci", hi: "hewd" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "7hbdS3MgfZ73TOtlu1WfXw",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "dummy" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      testingNewValue: { "en-us": "sdcoklsdc" },
      locationField: { hi: "sdcndkdc" },
    },
  },
];
  result = data.reduce(
    (
      r,
      {
        system: {
          id,
          content: {
            type: { name },
          },
        },
        DataDetails,
      }
    ) => {
      r[name] ??= {};
      Object.entries(DataDetails).forEach(([key, object]) => {
        Object.entries(object).forEach(([loc, value]) => {
          r[name][loc] ??= {};
          r[name][loc][id] ??= {};
          r[name][loc][id][key] = value; 
        });
      });
      return r;
    },
    {}
  );

console.log(result)
```

my this is my object

### fields

```
{
  "Author": { "fields": "shortSlugOption" },
  "testing": { "fields": "mediaaccess" },
  "dummy": { "fields": "fieldtest" },
  "new": { "fields": "fieldtest" },
}
```

I am trying to check and assign the value which is present inside the fields object with the key which is present in side result obj and assign the value

so in the fields object

```
"new": { "fields": "oneReference" }
```

I want to check the oneReference present in `new`

```
  "new": {
    "hi": {
      "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW": {
        "oneReference": "values 1",
        "media": {
          "conf": {
            "type": "media",
            "id": "01"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "hi-In": {
      "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW": {
        "multiReference": "values 2"
      }
    },
    "hi-IN": {
      "cIb5mqEBRWDD6hrNmFmFE": {
        "testingNewValue": "jksdsdo"
      }
    }
  },
```

so here my expected output is like this

### Expected Output

```
  "new": {
    "hi": {
      "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW": {
        "subject": "values 1"
        "id": "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW",
        "address": "/new/values 1"
        "oneReference": "values 1",
        "media": {
          "conf": {
            "type": "media",
            "id": "01"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "hi-In": {
      "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW": {
        "subject": "unknown"
        "id": "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW",
        "address": "/new/unknown"
        "multiReference": "values 2"
      }
    },
    "hi-IN": {
      "cIb5mqEBRWDD6hrNmFmFE": {
        "subject": "unknown"
        "id": "cIb5mqEBRWDD6hrNmFmFE",
        "address": "/new/unknown"
        "testingNewValue": "jksdsdo"
      }
    }
  },

"Author": {
    "en-us": {
      "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA": {
        "subject": "some value",
        "id": "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA",
        "address": "Author/some value",
        "shortSlugOption": "some value",
        "mediaFileAssetLink": "some file",
        "singleMediaImage": "english link"
      }
    },
    "za-op": {
      "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA": {
        "subject": "random value",
        "id": "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA",
        "address": "Author/random value",
        "shortSlugOption": "random value",
        "mediaFileAssetLink": "file Linl"
      }
    },
    "hi": {
      "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA": {
        "subject": "unknown",
        "id": "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA",
        "address": "Author/unknown",
        "mediaFileAssetGalary": "file link 2",
        "singleMediaImage": "file link single"
      }
    }
  }
```

here we can see  `new:hi` and `new:hi-In` contain same id `66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW` so its should check field object `oneReference` present in which id and assign that value in `subject` but in the `new:hi-IN` the id `cIb5mqEBRWDD6hrNmFmFE` does not contain `oneReference` then it should print `unknown` like this I want to check for `Author testing dummy` and many more if they are present in the `fields` object and check the value present or not in the `result` and display Unknown if the value is not present but display the actual key value

so I tried this but no help

```js
let field = {
  Author: { fields: "shortSlugOption" },
  testing: { fields: "mediaaccess" },
  dummy: { fields: "fieldtest" },
  new: { fields: "fieldtest" },
};

const data = [
  {
    system: {
      id: "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "Author" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      shortSlugOption: { "en-us": "some value", "za-op": "random value" },
      mediaFileAssetLink: { "en-us": "some file", "za-op": "file Linl" },
      mediaFileAssetGalary: { hi: "file link 2" },
      singleMediaImage: { hi: "file link single", "en-us": "english link" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "1aBOO8tu3lUsjtICuIbUM5",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "Author" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      short: { "en-us": ["shorts", "values"], "za-op": "short details" },
      shortSlugOption: { "hi-In": "options" },
      booleanField: { "hi-In": "true" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "2pOUGnI1oRD7nsrYs600HA",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "testing" } },
    },
    DataDetails: { testingNewValue: { "en-us": "details value" } },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "new" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      oneReference: { hi: "values 1" },
      multiReference: { "hi-In": "values 2" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "cIb5mqEBRWDD6hrNmFmFE",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "new" } },
    },
    DataDetails: { testingNewValue: { "hi-IN": "jksdsdo" } },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "7kRzyt4PFrX13gHcw3Z1Ko",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "testing" } },
    },
    DataDetails: { testingNewValue: { "en-us": "kknksdo" } },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "2OspeCtNK0sh2cPiuU9jIz",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "dummy" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      short: { "za-op": "dfvndkssa" },
      shortSlugOption: { hi: "sdocjosmdc" },
      mediaFileAssetLink: { "en-us": "jdsojocis" },
      booleanField: { "hi-In": "true" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "2eAmIIuG4xkLvatkU3RUSy",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "dummy" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      dummy: { "en-us": "dshcifdvk" },
      india: { "za-op": "sdci", hi: "hewd" },
    },
  },
  {
    system: {
      id: "7hbdS3MgfZ73TOtlu1WfXw",
      type: "Entry",
      content: { type: { name: "dummy" } },
    },
    DataDetails: {
      testingNewValue: { "en-us": "sdcoklsdc" },
      locationField: { hi: "sdcndkdc" },
    },
  },
];

Object.keys(field).map((type) => {
  const searchKey = field[type]?.fields;

  result = data.reduce(
    (
      r,
      {
        system: {
          id,
          content: {
            type: { name },
          },
        },
        DataDetails,
      }
    ) => {
      r[name] ??= {};
      Object.entries(DataDetails).forEach(([key, object]) => {
        Object.entries(object).forEach(([loc, value]) => {
          r[name][loc] ??= {};
          r[name][loc][id] ??= {subject:"hello", id:id, address:`${name}/hello`};
          r[name][loc][id][key] = value;
          
        });
      });
      console.log(r);
      return r;
    },
    {}
  );
  
  const typeObject = result[type] ?? {};
  let subject;
  outer: for (key in typeObject) {
    const value = typeObject[key];
    subject = null;
    for (subkey in value) {
      const subvalue = value[subkey];
      subject = subvalue[searchKey];
      if (subject != null) break;
    }
    console.log(subject ?? "Unknown");
  }
});
```

In place of `hello` I am trying to get the value of `shortSlugOption` and other values which are present inside the `field` Object but if the `shortSlugOption` present in `en-us za-op or hi` then it should take first value from this key if the `shortSlugOption` is not present inside `en-us` then it should print `unknown` in `en-us`while in `za-op` and assign that value but if in `en-us and za-op` the value is not present then it should print `unknown`  and check the other `hi` like this but as we can see `Author en-us 1aBOO8tu3lUsjtICuIbUM5`  does not contain `shortSlugOption` then it should print `unknown` in place of `hello`

Comment: No, it's not, if you're not going to store the resulted array `map` returns. If you don't need the array, use `forEach` instead of `map`. It's also notable, that `map` works with arrays only, you can't iterate an object using `map`.

Comment: ok but fetching type from nested object can be possible by forEach function ? @Teemu

Comment: `forEach` has lower performance than plain `for` loop, so you may use `for` loop on this.

Comment: what exactly is the question here?

Comment: if you have resolved this question, you should close it to stop people from wasting their time trying to help you.

Comment: Its in bounty I tried to close it. Once the bounty get over I will close it @henk

Comment: what is actually the qiestion? what do you have and what do you want?

Comment: @NinaScholz I am trying to get the value of `shortSlugOption` and other values which are present inside the `field Object` but if the `shortSlugOption` present in `en-us za-op or hi` then it should take first value from this key if the `shortSlugOption` is not present inside `en-us` then it should check `za-op` and assign that value but if in `en-us` and `za-op` the value is not present then it should check the other `hi` like this but as we can see `Author en-us 1aBOO8tu3lUsjtICuIbUM5`  does not contain `shortSlugOption` then it should print `unknown` in place of `hello`

Comment: @NinaScholz for better understanding you can see expected output what I really want :)

Comment: is the expected output the complete result?

Comment: yes @NinaScholz

Comment: from which fields is it the result? for first with more or the second with only one property?

Comment: @NinaScholz like for more clear understanding I have just updated my question as we can see `shortSlugOption` value present in `en-us` and `za-op` then it should assign that value but in `hi` `shortSlugOption` not present then it should print `unknown` in subject` like this I wanted to assign for all the required values :)

Answer (score 2):

Hello in this case I will say that trying to user Array function will make the code too unclear.
Sometime you may need to use function ;)

```
let result = {}

const mapMedia = (val) => {
    if (val instanceof Array) {
        return val.map(mapMedia).filter(i => !!i)
    }
    if (val && val.conf && val.conf.type === 'media' && val.conf.id) {
        return mediaObj[val.conf.id] || null
    }
    return undefined
}

const getLocalizedDataForAuthor = (locale, author) => {
    return result && result[locale] && result[locale][author] || null
}

const addLocalizedDataForAuthor = (locale, author, key, value) => {
    if (key && value) {
        if (!result[locale]) { // create the locale in result if not existing
            result[locale] = {}
        }
        if (!result[locale][author]) { // create the author in result if not existing
            result[locale][author] = {}
        }
        result[locale][author][key] = value
    }
    
}

data.forEach(authorInitialData => { // authorInitialData : {system, DataDetails}
    for (const key in authorInitialData.DataDetails) {
        const localizedData = authorInitialData.DataDetails[key]
        for (const locale in localizedData) {
            const authorFinalData = {}
            var finalData = localizedData[locale]
            const media = mapMedia(finalData)
            if (media !== undefined) { // is not a media
                addLocalizedDataForAuthor(locale, authorInitialData.system.id, key, media)
            } else {
                addLocalizedDataForAuthor(locale, authorInitialData.system.id, key, finalData)
            }
            const author = getLocalizedDataForAuthor(locale, authorInitialData.system.id)
            if (author) {
                author.subject = author.subject || 'unknown'
                author.address = author.address || '/new/unknown'
            }
        }
    }
})

console.log(result)
```

If you really want to use only Array function you will hae to use `Object.keys(yourObject).arrayFunction( arrayFunctionCallback )`

Comment: Hi @Merlin sorry but I have solved that question :) can you help me in the updated question ?

Comment: I've updated the code, I had to make only a few changes to make it match you're demande.
Also you removed the mediaObj snippet from your original question so it's almost impossible to respond you demande.